# Node.js server just keeps loading with no result

Tags: node.js

server.js

```
const http = require('http');
const app  = require('./app');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(port);
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const productRoutes = require('./api/routes/products');
app.use('/products', productRoutes);
module.exports = app;
```

so when i just run the code node server.js it just keep looping without any result.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: what do you wanna do with this server? be more specific please

Comment: How does productRoutes look like?

Comment: `app` is used twice, with `require('./app')` and `express()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [link](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connect)  It gives a bit more detail on how that works.

```
const http = require('http');
const net = require('net');
const url = require('url');

// Create an HTTP tunneling proxy
const proxy = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('okay');
});
proxy.on('connect', (req, cltSocket, head) => {
  // connect to an origin server
  const srvUrl = url.parse(`http://${req.url}`);
  const srvSocket = net.connect(srvUrl.port, srvUrl.hostname, () => {
    cltSocket.write('HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established\r\n' +
                    'Proxy-agent: Node.js-Proxy\r\n' +
                    '\r\n');
    srvSocket.write(head);
    srvSocket.pipe(cltSocket);
    cltSocket.pipe(srvSocket);
  });
});

// now that proxy is running
proxy.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1', () => {

  // make a request to a tunneling proxy
  const options = {
    port: 1337,
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    method: 'CONNECT',
    path: 'www.google.com:80'
  };

  const req = http.request(options);
  req.end();

  req.on('connect', (res, socket, head) => {
    console.log('got connected!');

    // make a request over an HTTP tunnel
    socket.write('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
                 'Host: www.google.com:80\r\n' +
                 'Connection: close\r\n' +
                 '\r\n');
    socket.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(chunk.toString());
    });
    socket.on('end', () => {
      proxy.close();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This should be in comment not an answer

Comment: please provide more details and a direct answer then refer to the link. Imagine the link is no longer valid, this way your answer will last "forever".

Answer (score 0):

```
const http = require('http');
const app  = require('./app');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(port);
```

As far I could extract from code, the thing that is most probably happening in your server.js is that your server is waiting for some request. And you have nothing in your code handle requests.

Comment: thanks i just forget to app the parameter over here 
       const server = http.createServer(app);

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to call the `require` function to return the actual `router` object, try to change this line

from:  `const productRoutes = require('./api/routes/products');`

to:    `const productRoutes = require('./api/routes/products')();`